# php curl not retrieving as expected

Tags: php, curl

I have the following code to capture the html code of a given url:

```
$url = "https://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/exibirDocumento?id=77212&cvm=true";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, '/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

    $html = curl_exec($ch);

    echo "$url\n\n";
    die($html);
```

For some reason the result of the following url is not as expected:

```
"https://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/exibirDocumento?id=77212&cvm=true"
```

Instead of the code, the result is a giant meaningless string.

- I've have successfully used the same code with other pages of the same domain.
- I can assure that the desired page's content is not loaded by any js/ajax method (i did the test loading the page when disabling javascript).

**My question is:**
There is any cUrl option that i should set to correct this error?

My whole site depends on capturing this pages.
Any help would be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

That is base64 encoded, all you need to do is decode it back to plain text like this

```
echo base64_decode($html);
```

and you will see HTML

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much!